# getting insight media data (like comments and location) of public Instagram account (not business) from Instagram API

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

my requirement is to get instagram user media data (like_count,comments,location).it was going fine with instagram Api until it announced it to deprecating those APi and shifted to Facebook Instagram Graph APi and Instagram Basic Display API.i cant use Graph APi as it will require user to have business account but yes users have to make account public.with Instagram Basic display Api we cannot have media insights (like_count,comments,location).i can extract data of public user from _sharedData variable  using  https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/ response. will that be alright? because if i have hundred thousand users,i will be making those requests to Instagram at a time. will Instagram  restrict me of doing this action?is there another solution of getting using media data?

Comment: This is not possible with the Basic Display API yet.

Comment: yeah,they are providing only caption,media_id,url_image,timestamp of media in basic display api. this data is insufficient.whats the point of even making this api.they should have at least provide more data for public account or maybe allow public accounts which are not business in Graph Api.